# VBA: Using a Two-Dimensional Array to Populate Multiple Different Combo Boxes

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, combobox

I'm very new to using VBA, so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

I have a two-dimensional string array, ArrayCBO. I want to use each column of the array to populate a different combo box.

After I create the array in UserForm (Initialize), I tried using the following command to populate the combo box, cbo:

```
cbo.Column() = ArrayCBO
```

This works for the first column of ArrayCBO, but I can't figure out how to use it with the other columns!

I have also tried

```
cbo.Column() = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ArrayCBO, 0, 2)
```

to no avail. (The combo box's list appears empty.)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign to `.List`:

```
 cbo.List = ArrayCBO
```

Comment: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Just a little heads up =)

Comment: Thanks, Alex. But how do I specify the column of the array that I want to populate the list? I've tried
`cbo.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ArrayCBO, 0, 1)`

Comment: If you want to do something other than the default outcome of assigning to `.List` then AFAIK you will need to loop the array and add manually.